# Connect to localhost with iPad

Tags: asp.net, ipad, networking

Trying to connect to localhost on my development machine with my iPad using wifi.
The webserver integrated in Visual studio.

Using ip number I get from ipconfig.

```
192.168.1.84:1144
```

I'm receiving http 400 error.

I've added port 1144 as TCP/IP port on firewall.

Anybody knows what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

does your machine have a static IP? with DHCP enabled, the ip of your machine keeps changing every now and then, so it might be the case that the address provided is no longer available!!

disconnect and reconnect to your network, then run ipconfig again and check if the IP has changed, if it has, then DHCP is enabled...

Comment: ip address has not changed

Comment: try and put the same address on the same computer and check if it is working, im presuming you have some sort of a test html file or something under the root folder...

Comment: i tried to use the ip-address instead of localhost and it did not work.

Comment: so what i understand is, that you put the ip address on the SAME COMPUTER the server is running on and it did not work? If that is the case the binding of the address has not been done correctly...just to be on the safer side, do you know how to set a static ip? if yes, do that...

Comment: i tried but it did not work. Look at update for config, maybe you can see whats wrong

Comment: is it working with localhost? what is exactly that youre putting in address bar, so technically it should be working with localhost:1144/test.html, then try again with 192.168.1.84:1144/test.html assuming youve put in the test.html file in the root folder...

Comment: Is there maybe a security setting to allow other computer in to the development computer?

Comment: Its an ASP.NET MVC application

Comment: For some reason the browser seams to have a problem with ip-addresses. When i tried http://127.0.0.1:1144/ instead of localhost:1144 it did not work.